# mongo uri for springboot get request

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have configure mongo uri in property file as below,

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db1.dev.com,db2.dev.com,db3.dev.com
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
```

I use mongoowl as a monitoring tool. 
When i do a get request, it shows hits in every mongodb which ideally should be show only in one db right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You are actually opening a cluster replica set connection, in this connection type spring actually connects to all 3 databases to maintain fail over conditions or to full fill "read from secondary" option(hence you see hits on all 3 databases), but however the read and write operations happen only on primary unless you have specified it to read from a secondary.